# Map response data to required structure of domain model

Tags: mendix

I am consuming REST services through API in `Mendix` application. But the JSON response received is not in the format I need in `Mendix` domain model (*for the UI*).

How can I achieve this conversion?

Currently I am using import mapping generated automatically using JSON structure to hold the response. And I want to convert this mapping to required structure of domain model.

Any other solution to capture response and process it to required domain model will also be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

So you generated entities in your domain model to map the JSON to?

That's not necessary, you you can use the import mapping to map the JSON directly to the domain model entities that you need.